# Does a mysql query write temp tables to disk and what exactly is it writing?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on optimizing a `mysql` query that joins 2 tables together and has a few where clauses and an order by.

I noticed (using explain) that a temporary table is created during the evaluation of the query.  (since I'm grouping on a field in a table that isn't the first table in the join queue)

I'd really like to know if this temp table is being written to disk or not, which the explain results don't tell me.

It would also be nice to be able to tell what exactly is going into said temporary table.  Some of the restrictions in my where clause are on indexed columns and some aren't, so I think that mysql might not be optimally picking rows into the temporary table.

Specifically, my query is basically of the form: select ... from a join b where ... with restrictions on both a and b on both indexed and non-indexed columns.  The problem is that the number of rows going into the temp table selected from a is more than I suspect it should be.  I want to investigate this.

Answer (score -2):

All databases use a memory area or work area to execute a query and will use temp tables in those memory areas depending on how you built your query. If your joining multiple tables it may use more than one to build the final result set. Those temp tables usually exist in memory as long as the user is logged on.

Explain is illustrating the process it is trying to optimize as it interprets your SQL. If you have a poorly indexed where clause or if you are using a where clause in a join it could be pulling an excessive amount of data into memory as it executes and builds your final result set. This is what poor performance at the DB level looks like.

By reading your pseudo code in the last paragraph I would say you need some indexing and to rewrite your Where clause to join on indexed fields. Post your SQL if you really want an opinion.

Comment: Doesn't answer the user's questions. The user specifically asked how he might be able to tell whether a particular query is writing its temporary tables to disk, and if there's a way to see what exactly is going into these temporary tables in the first place.